# Does Linux use some of the solutions of priority inversion?

Tags: linux, multithreading, concurrency, linux-kernel, posix

As known, priority inversion problem - when a thread with higher priority waits for a thread with lower-priority: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion

It happen when we have 3 threads: L (low), M (medium), H (high-priority). L and H use the same mutex, but L acquire it early than H, and H blocked and goes to sleep. And then M occupies CPU-core because has higher priority than L, and L goes to sleep, but mutex still acquired. L & H are sleeping, but M is working.

There are some [solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion#Solutions) of priority inversion:

- **Disabling all interrupts** to protect critical sections
- **A priority ceiling**
- **Priority inheritance**
- **Random boosting** - Ready tasks holding locks are randomly boosted in priority until they exit the critical section. This solution is used in **Microsoft Windows**.
- **Avoid blocking**

Does Linux use some of the solutions of priority inversion, and which of its?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux uses **Priority inheritance**.

Priority inversion can be solved by using function [`int pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol(pthread_mutexattr_t *attr, int protocol);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol)

Where `protocol` is:

- `PTHREAD_PRIO_NONE` - nothing going on when acquires mutex ownership
- `PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT` - [Priority inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inheritance)
- `PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT` - uses a fixed level of the priority in accordance with `prioceiling` value which got by function [`pthread_mutexattr_getprioceiling()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling)

> When a thread owns one or more mutexes initialized with the
>   PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT protocol, it shall execute at the higher of its
>   priority or the highest of the priority ceilings of all the mutexes
>   owned by this thread and initialized with this attribute, regardless
>   of whether other threads are blocked on any of these mutexes or not.

Comment: PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT doesn't seem to be supported by linux